# Storing multiline text to an xml field and showing it in a gridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, gridview, line-breaks, multiline

The title says it all.
The problem is the line breaks.

I used what I'd found in a forum, to replace the vb line breaks to

```
dr("Description") = TxtDescription.Text.Replace(vbCr & vbLf, "<br />")
```

But in the gridview where the data in the xml files are shown, the `<br />` was written out, like a part of the string stored. I opened xml file, and the `<br />` was in black, like the other words of the string.

Any idea how I should do this?

Comment: <br /> is not recognized as xml but HTML.

Comment: oh... then, what's the equivalent in xml?

Comment: there is no linefeed in xml. XML is data, it doesn't know about formatting. You could probably do something like this using an xslt (but i am not really sure), or you could create parse the xml and pass it in the gridview.  We could help if we could see a sample xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an intermediate code to determine the line breaks, for example:

```
dr("Description") = TxtDescription.Text.Replace(Envinronment.NewLine(), "#Line#")
```

And then, when you read your xml, replace all the `#Line#` codes with a `<br />`.

Comment: This did the trick. Didn't think of doing it the other way around before. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Be sure the code string you use could not appear in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following code:

```
Dim xdoc As XDocument = New XDocument( _
                            New XDeclaration( _
                                 "1.0", "utf-8", nothing), _
                                 New XElement( _
                                     "root", _
                                     TxtDescription.Lines.Select( _
                                         Function(x) New XElement("Data",x) _
                                     ) _
                                 ) _
                             )
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim reader As XmlReader = xdoc.CreateReader()

ds.ReadXml(reader)
GridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```